# Creating a time bar for video

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, timeline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5sBU.png)
How do I add **small lines** within a div element as per the image.
The div in question is the #holder in the code below.

```
<div class="video-holder"><!-- The video-->
      <video width="100%" height="100%" controls src="videos/video 1.mp4" id="myvideo" oncanplay="myf()"></video>
</div><br>
<div id="holder"></div> <!-- The timeline div-->

function myf(){
var mydiv = document.getElementById('holder');
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvidlen = myvid.duration;

var mydivwidth = myvidlen * 20;
mydiv.style.width = mydivwidth + "px";//sets the width of the timeline div
```

}

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. This is unfortunately not what stackoverflow is made for. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please do some research on your own and try to do some code before posting something on stack overflow.

Comment: I believe I have posted as per the rules. I however, tried to do the code but all I can get to is creating the div and getting the time from the video.
I just need a way to create the lines I suppose.

Comment: Then post the code you did, we don't bite ;) 
For the line, you could create the lines with a styled element such as a span.

Comment: Just updated it.
What if the duration of the video is one hour? It means there would be almost 180 spans for every 20 seconds.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could also generate them, keep them while they must be viewed and then remove them. Or even better, once they are not viewed, make them invisible, move them back at the end and re-make them visible when required.

Comment: Thank you. I stressfully searched the internet and I may have found the answer. I might use the canvas element -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp